# Django and Nginx (Digital Ocean)

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I am finishing my first project in Django and in deployment I'm facing a problem.

when I enter the site, I get the Nginx default page.
I followed all the steps in the tutorial, read it again, so I don't know what I am missing.

Here are the codes:

[Gunicorn Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssd03.png)

[Nginx Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsWb0.png)

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANAId.png)

Comment: did you reload nginx service after making modification

Comment: Please, use stackoverflow editor to showcase the code, not screenshots. We're unable to copy from screenshots ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes, I reloaded the nginx services, but didn't work.

Comment: About the screenshots, I did because I am using putty, I don't know if I can copy from it, but as soon as I get home I will work on it, thanks

Comment: What are you using when accessing the site from the browser? IP? a host name? In your nginx, you need to fix (or better) the server name. Also, consider making the sever the default server by adding changing the listen directive to  `listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;`

Comment: I'm using IP. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: It didn't work @Oliver

Comment: Did you remove `server_name` after adding `default_server`?

Comment: No, but I destroyed that droplet and restarted all again, it seems to be working now, I really don't understand what happened. Thanks for your support!